# Combinatorics (Combinations and Permutations)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I had a math test recently but still can't find the answer to one of the questions which looks rather easy. Here it is:

> You are planning a 3-day camping trip, and want to buy easy-to-cook meals from your local shop. The shop stocks 5 varieties of main course and 5 varieties of desserts. You decide to buy 3 different main courses and 3 different desserts. How many options are available to you? (You are not yet thinking about which dessert to combine with which main course.)
>
> [A]100 [B]125 [C]243 [D]400

My logic was that for both the main course and the dessert we have ${5\choose 3} = 10$
And then for the first day we have 10*10=100, 9*9=81 for the second and 8*8=64 for the third, but that is equal to 245. I am really confused because it looks so simple, yet the answers don't match.

Comment: The question is, how many possible ways there are to buy 3 deserts and 3 main courses. You don't consider the days. Just how many possible combination of six things you can buy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\binom 53=10$ ways to choose the three main courses and $\binom 53=10$ ways to choose the three desserts.

Thus there are $10\times 10=100$ ways to select your foods.

Comment: That was my initial guess and actual answer, but then again why is the 3-day thing even mentioned and the "tip" in the brackets?

Comment: We are simply counting the number of different combinations of food we can walk away from the store with. The information in the brackets alludes to actually counting the different menus we can create once we have the selection from the store. On the first day you would have $3\times 3=9$ choices, on the second day you would have $2\times 2=4$ choices, and on the third day you would have $1$ choice